# Initialize class variable with function inside the class

Tags: php, class

I have class something like that:

```
class Example{
    private $a;
    private $b;

    function Example($user){
        $this->a = $user;
        $this->b = getsting();    //here is my problem
    }

    function getstring(){
        return "string".$this->a; //here I have a class variable
    }
}
```

How can I return value to `$b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the class, you need to use `$this->` to refer to other functions.

```
$this->b = $this->getstring();
```

P.S. It's `getstring`, not `getsting`.

Comment: Sorry I edit my question because I forgot that I have a class var inside the function

Answer (score 0):

```
class Example
{
  private $a;
  private $b;

  function Example($user)
  {
    $this->userid=$user;
    $this->b=$this->getstring();    //use $this-> before the method name
  }

  function getstring()
  {
    return "string";
  }
}
```